# LINQ Right Join

Tags: mysql, sql, linq, lambda, right-join

I have checked all forum in stack overflow but for some reason I can not find a solution for a simple SQL join which seam to me almost impossible in LinQ, but probably I misunderstand.

I have 3 tables and the sql join look like this:

```
school: name, id
class:  name, id
chair:  name, id
```

To do:
the table [class] and [chair] are always hard joined
the table [school] always needs to be there also when class and chair do not exist

```
Select school.name, class.name, chair.name 
from school 
right outer join class on class.id = school.id
join chair on chair.id = class.id
```

It seems to me using the combination of   {groupjoin} and {join} do not the job

Comment: What you describe ("the table [school] always needs to be there") requires a left outer join. But if you're using something like Entity Framework you should move your focus away from translating SQL into LINQ. Instead, use navigation properties and EF will figure out the correct types of joins.

Answer (score 0):

> the table [school] always needs to be there also when class and chair do not exist

This means that you need either `school LEFT JOIN (class, chair)` or `(class, chair) RIGHT JOIN school`.

I.e. either

```sql
SELECT school.name, class.name, chair.name 
FROM school 
LEFT JOIN (      class 
            JOIN chair ON chair.id = class.id) ON class.id = school.id
```

or

```sql
SELECT school.name, class.name, chair.name
FROM class 
JOIN chair ON chair.id = class.id
RIGHT JOIN school ON class.id = school.id
```

[Modelling fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=78bbe79108469952dd1c84f4fc093cef)